# Does Ubuntu touch OS uses Compiz to perform animations

Tags: compiz, ubuntu-touch

If so, is it possible to have effects like Wobbly in Ubuntu Touch?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch uses Unity 8, which uses Mir & Qt rather than Compiz for that

Answer (score 0):

No. Ubuntu touch uses Mir as the compositor. There is no clue about having Compiz like effects with Mir.